# LINQ to SQL: table insert on multiple tables

Tags: sql, linq, insert

I have two tables, RESTAURANT and HOURS with REST_ID as the key between the two tables.  i receive an error when I get to the first line of code to add HOURs.  The error asks to create an instance of the object but Intellisence allows me to call that table reference.  Here is a snipped of the code:

```
RESTAURANT addRest = new RESTAURANT();
    addRest.REST_NAME = r_name;
    addRest.REST_STREET1 = r_street;
    addRest.REST_PHONE = r_phone;
    addRest.REST_WEBSITE = r_web;
    addRest.REST_DESC = r_desc;
    addRest.HOUR.HOURS_SUN = h_su;
    addRest.HOUR.HOURS_MON = h_mo;
    addRest.HOUR.HOURS_TUE = h_tu;
    addRest.HOUR.HOURS_WED = h_we;
    addRest.HOUR.HOURS_THU = h_th;
    addRest.HOUR.HOURS_FRI = h_fr;
    addRest.HOUR.HOURS_SAT = h_sa;
    addRest.HOURReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("FVTCEntities.HOURS", "HOURS", 1);
    db.AddToRESTAURANTs(addRest);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HOUR` is a contained object inside of `RESTAURANT`.  You need to instantiate it before setting properties on it (like a typical C# object):

```
addRest.HOUR = new HOUR();
addRest.HOUR.HOURS_SUN = h_su;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't created an HOUR object on your RESTAURANT, so that navigation property is `null`.

```
...
addRest.REST_DESC = r_desc;
addRest.HOUR = new HOUR();
addRest.HOUR.HOURS_SUN = h_su;
...
```